# MySQL left join that shows NULL for missing rows

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables

Table:

```
recip
recipid | recipname
  1     |   Recip1
  2     |   Recip2
```

And table:

```
recipuser
recipid | userid
  1     |  1
  2     |  1
  1     |  2
```

So userid 2 has 1 recip

The result I'm trying to achieve is to show all "recip" rows with matching or null for given user id, EG:

```
SELECT r.recipid, r.recipname, ru.userid
FROM recip r
left JOIN recipuser ru ON r.recipid = ru.recipid
WHERE ru.userid = 2 OR ru.userid IS NULL
```

Results in:

```
recipid | recipname | userid
  1     |   Recip1  |   2
```

I want to get:

```
recipid | recipname | userid
  1     |   Recip1  |   2
  2     |   Recip2  |   NULL
```

How do I show all rows from recip with the userid or NULL for every row given a user id??

Thanks for your help.

Comment: The example is not sufficiently representative of the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the `WHERE` logic to the `ON` clause:

```
SELECT r.recipid, r.recipname, ru.userid
FROM recip r
LEFT JOIN recipuser ru
    ON r.recipid = ru.recipid AND ru.userid = 2;
```

The problem with your current query is that the `WHERE` clause is filtering off the non matching record which you want to appear.

Comment: Thanks Tim, I didn't realise that was possible. Still trying to phrase the logic of what you did.